# ssh returns "Bad owner or permissions on ~/.ssh/config"

Tags: ssh, file-permissions

When I try to ssh to another box, I get this strange error

```
$ ssh hostname
Bad owner or permissions on ~/.ssh/config
```

But I made sure that I own and have rw permissions on the file:

```
ls -la ~/.ssh/
total 40K
drwx------ 2 robert robert 4.0K Mar 29 11:04 ./
drwx------ 7 robert robert 4.0K Mar 29 11:04 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert robert 2.0K Mar 17 20:47 authorized_keys
-rw-rw-r-- 1 robert robert   31 Mar 29 11:04 config
-rw------- 1 robert robert 1.7K Aug  4  2010 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert robert  406 Aug  4  2010 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert robert 6.1K Mar 29 11:03 known_hosts
```

Comment: I just had the same message. My case was different. I was having a global `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa` set, so when I was trying to access user@myserver.com it was trying to use that id_rsa without questioning me the password. Avoid the global IdentityFile and it will all go well.

Comment: This happened to me on macOS after installing SourceTree - I opened up the `config` file and found there was nothing useful in it, just generated code by SourceTree, which I no longer use anyway. Removing the file (renaming it to config.bak) solved my issue!

Answer (score 870, accepted):

I needed to have rw for user only permissions on config.  This fixed it.

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

As others have noted below, it could be the file owner.  (upvote them!)

```
chown $USER ~/.ssh/config
```

If your whole folder has invalid permissions here's a table of possible permissions:

| Path | Permission |
| --- | --- |
| .ssh directory ([code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/2dc328023f60212cd29504fc05d849133ae47355/regress/check-perm.c#L131)) | 0700 (drwx------) |
| private keys (ex: `id_rsa`) ([code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/c25c84074a47f700dd6534995b4af4b456927150/readconf.c#L2257)) | 0600 (-rw-------) |
| `config` | 0600 (-rw-------) |
| public keys (*.pub ex: `id_rsa.pub`) | 0644 (-rw-r--r--) |
| `authorized_keys` ([code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/2dc328023f60212cd29504fc05d849133ae47355/contrib/cygwin/ssh-user-config#L154)) | 0644 (-rw-r--r--) |
| `known_hosts` | 0644 (-rw-r--r--) |

Sources:

- openssh [check-perm.c](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/2dc328023f60212cd29504fc05d849133ae47355/regress/check-perm.c#L131)
- openssh [readconf.c](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/c25c84074a47f700dd6534995b4af4b456927150/readconf.c#L2257)
- openssh ssh_user_config [fix_authorized_keys_perms](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/2dc328023f60212cd29504fc05d849133ae47355/contrib/cygwin/ssh-user-config#L154)

Comment: Sometimes it's not only the permissions, but also the owner that can cause the problem; in my case, I had to do this as well: `chown -R robert:robert ~/.ssh`

Comment: In my case, going from 644 to 600 did the trick.

Comment: Just read permission should be sufficient, i.e. `400`

Comment: For me, `600` didn't work, only `400` (on Ubuntu Xenial)

Comment: @030 As long as you don't intend to edit the file..

Comment: You have to be the only one who can read or write that file, otherwise other people can compromise your security. Any other owner or r/w permission makes the file untrustworthy and therefore it is not used.

Comment: My file was empty. Setting any permissions did not help, so I deleted it. Then it worked.

Comment: To my surprise, 660 is considered "Bad owner or permissions on ~/.ssh/config" but 600 isn't.  Thanks!

Comment: Fresh Fedora (i am loving the ws30) install. This was causing trouble and 0600 mod fixed it. Thanks @Robert

Comment: chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config - it worked for me, thanks!

Comment: @HCSF "Because of the potential for abuse, this file [.ssh/config] must have strict permissions: read/write for the user, and not writable by others", cf. https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#FILES . The other approaches did not work for me. Indeed, I can recommend to run `chmod 0700 ~/.ssh` and then `chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/*` to correctly set the permissions for the whole .ssh directory.

Comment: "You have to be the only one who can read or write that file" as @simpleuser said (and most others ment) is accurate. Wording matters because there is another way to mess this up: If you add another account to your group (see /etc/groups) you will not be the only user any more. That quirk doesn't show in neither permissions nor owner of `~/.ssh/*`

Comment: I'm just wondering. What kind of things cause these permissions to become reversed? I came back to my terminal and was surprised that I couldn't access my Git repo anymore because of this (and the solution fixed the issue). What the heck?

Answer (score 111):

These commands should fix the permission problem:

```
chown $USER ~/.ssh/config
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/config
```

Prefix with `sudo` if the files are owned by different user (or you don't have access to them).

If more files are affected, replace `config` with `*`.

In `man ssh` we can read:

> Because of the potential for abuse, this file must have strict permissions: read/write for the user, and not
>   writable by others.  It may be group-writable provided that the group in question contains only the user.

Comment: This did the trick for me. I am using cygwin and cygwin .ssh is symlinked to windows user .ssh. I had to run those commands in cygwin window.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me. `chown` was not necessary, since the file was already owned from the right account. I was not understanding how the permissions could be wrong, until I read this answer.

Comment: Yep, I find myself coming back to this answer every now and then :-)

Answer (score 18):

For me it was an issue with my user account not being the owner of the file

```
sudo chown myuser ~/.ssh/config
```

Answer (score 15):

If on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and you pointed your WSL home directory to your Windows home directory (not recommended!) then chmod has no effect.  Before you can `chmod` the files mentioned in other answers you must add

```
[automount]
options = "metadata"
```

to your `/etc/wsl.conf` then restart WSL (requires build 17093 or later).

Before mount says:

```
C: on /mnt/c type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off)
```

After mount says:

```
C: on /mnt/c type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,metadata,case=off)
```

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 Version 1903 and chmod in WSL just worked.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget about the group:

```
chown $USER:$USER ~/.ssh/config
```

:-)

Comment: The group does not matter if the file is not group writable. If it is, the group must at most contain the user.

Comment: I just thought that if this file unexpectedly has a wrong user, it also can have a wrong group. To make all things right we'd better take an attention on the group too.

Answer (score 1):

I met this issue on windows 10 with `vagrant ssh`. And tried all the above methods, but get no luck. Finally I deleted that ssh config file and then it works!

```
vagrant ssh
Bad owner or permissions on C:\\Users\\Jeff/.ssh/config
del ..\.ssh\config

vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-170-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Thu Feb 27 02:23:03 UTC 2020

  System load:  0.0               Processes:              77
  Usage of /:   5.1% of 39.34GB   Users logged in:        0
  Memory usage: 21%               IP address for eth0:    10.0.2.15
  Swap usage:   0%                IP address for docker0: 172.17.0.1

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

New release '16.04.6 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.


vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$
```

Comment: This doesn't help if I need the contents of the config file to be used when logging into a remote ssh host

Comment: this worked for me same issues vagrant ssh was not working created a backup of the config file and then tried vagrant ssh and it worked. Thanks