# ssh hostname returns “Bad owner or permissions on ~/.ssh/config” (chmod 600 not working with MingW)

Tags: ssh, git, chmod, rsa, gitolite

This question is a near duplicate of [Robert's question](https://serverfault.com/questions/253313/ssh-hostname-returns-bad-owner-or-permissions-on-ssh-config) but after trying `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config` I still have the same error.

I've tried using `cygwin` and `MINGW32` to do the `chmod 600`. `ls -la` returns `-rw-------` on `cygwin` and returns `-rw-r--r--` on `MINGW32`.

By these results, `cygwin` says that it does have the proper permissions and therefore shouldn't be complaining when I `ssh hostname`, however both `cygwin` and `MINGW32` complain when trying to ssh.

This is similar to [the issues I had with gitosis](https://serverfault.com/questions/284683/gitosis-installation-of-public-key-not-working) where [this article](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=261) said that I needed to switch over the `ssh.exe` files from `cygwin` to `git` (MINGW32) which did actually fix the issue at the time. However, this fix doesn't seem to be working any more as `MINGW32` isn't `chmod`ing properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure the permissions are reasonably restrictive on all ancestor directories as well.  For example, chmod 700 ~/.ssh and chmod 755 ~.

Comment: Also had to `chown _UserName_ config`. According to `cygwin` I wasn't the owner of the file, although `MINGW32`said I was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not to `chmod` but `chown` the file since `cygwin` said my account wasn't the owner of the file. Confusion was again in that `MINGW32` said I was the owner... Wish I had the skills to fix the `chmod` and `chown` in their project.

Answer (score 3):

Actually for me none of the above worked.

The inspiration came from http://yifanpeng.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/cygwin-ssh-tip.html

On linux you would just ensure the owner and group on your `.ssh` dir is `jujhar` by executing `chown jujhar.jujhar ~/.ssh` where `~` is a shortcut for `/home/jujhar`

The only difference with cygwin on windows is that the `jujhar` group is not created and you have to use the `Users` group.  Once that is set then you can `chmod` correctly.

In my case I did the following and it works great

```
chown jujhar.Users /cygdrive/c/Users/jujhar/.ssh
chmod 0700 /cygdrive/c/Users/jujhar/.ssh
chmod 0600 /cygdrive/c/Users/jujhar/.ssh/*
```

**NB** My home directory for my username `jujhar` is set to `/cygdrive/c/Users/jujhar` (you can change it in `/etc/passwd`.  This makes backups and stuff easier for me ([Crashplan](http://www.crashplan.com/) ftw.)

Answer (score 1):

Important note if your Windows is not in US English: the "users" group's name is locale-dependant. If your Windows is in Spanish, you'll have to change the files' ownership with `chown $USER:Usuarios *`